# Trying to export an excel file with the option to 'Save As' via tkinter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

As the title indicates, I'm creating an Excel file with Python and am trying to add in a 'Save As' tkinter function that will allow users to save the exported Excel file where they please. The excel file exports fine (by typing in the exact path), but creating the 'Save As' option is more difficult than anticipated. Below is the code as of now (with information omitted for obvious reasons), let me know if I can provide any other info for more context:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x150') 

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('')

script1=""

script2=""

df1 = pd.read_sql_query(script1, cnxn)
df2 = pd.read_sql_query(script2, cnxn)

def save(): 
    
    files = [("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),('All Files', '*.*')] 
    file = asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, defaultextension = files)

    df1.to_excel(file, sheet_name='Initial Appointment', index=False)
    df2.to_excel(file, sheet_name='Follow Ups', index=False)
  
btn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Save', command = lambda : save()) 
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 20) 
  
mainloop()
```

EDIT: The 'Save As' dialog box opens, but it doesn't save the Excel file, but rather the script, so it seems. I could save as an Excel file, but when opening it, I get an error saying it's not valid (which probably means whatever I saved wasn't meant for this format).

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? What does it do that is incorrect? Does `to_excel` expect a file _name_ or a file _handle_?

Comment: Forgot to add, my bad...But the 'Save As' dialog box opens, but it doesn't save the Excel file, but rather the script, so it seems. I could save as an Excel file, but when opening it, I get an error saying it's not valid (which probably means whatever I saved wasn't meant for this format).

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but hopefully it helps others.

I was facing this issue. I am working with openpyxl, tkinter on windows 10, and it was saving it, but it doesn't add the .xlsx extension, so a quick fix is to just add strings.

I'm posting this code in case anybody else has the same question:

**Important note:** make sure that you are running your script through the command prompt and using it as an administrator. Openpyxl writes stuff to windows, and sometimes it won't work if you are not running the command prompt as a normal user.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, colors, PatternFill
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series

root = Tk()
root.title('Example to save stuff to excel')
root.geometry('600x600')
    
def to_excel():    
    '''
    moving some data to excel or some other program that can open excel files such as open office
    '''
    filename_path =  filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = 'C:/', title = 'Save file as', filetypes = (('Archivos de excel','*.xls'),('All Files', '*.*')))
    filename_path = filename_path + '.xlsx'
    wb = Workbook()                                                         # Objeto de openpyxl, nos ayuda a crear sheets y el workbook principal
    ws1 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet_A', 0)               
    ws1.title = 'datos'
    x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
    y = np.arange(0, 400, 4)
    
    # pretty colors to put in your excel file
    yellowFill = PatternFill(start_color = '15D321', end_color = '15D321', fill_type = 'solid')
    greenFill = PatternFill(start_color = 'FFFF99', end_color = 'FFFF99', fill_type = 'solid')

    ws1['A1'].font = Font(bold = True)
    ws1['A1'].fill = greenFill
    ws1['B1'].fill = greenFill
    ws1.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = 'Ejemplo'
   
    ws1['A10'].font = Font(bold = True)
    ws1['A10'].fill = yellowFill
    ws1['B10'].font = Font(bold = True)
    ws1['B10'].fill = yellowFill
    ws1.cell(row = 10, column = 1).value = 'x'
    ws1.cell(row = 10, column = 2).value = 'y'

    row_j = 11
    for i in range(len(x)):
        ws1.cell(row = row_j, column = 1).value = x[i]
        ws1.cell(row = row_j, column = 2).value = y[i]
        row_j = row_j + 1
    
    wb.save(filename = filename_path)

save_label = Label(root, text = 'Save', padx = 5, pady = 5)
save_label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 5)

button_save = Button(root, text = 'Click me', padx = 5, pady = 5, command = to_excel)
button_save.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```